# Rx replay sequence of event at original pace (HistoricalScheduler ?)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

i recorded some events from a machine on the field (positioning data).
I would like to replay them like it was coming from the physical system to build simulations for the user.
I tried to do it with RX and HistoricalScheduler but without luck, is it possible to run it at original speed ?
Thanks

Example, i would like scheduler.Start() to take 5 seconds to execute with subscribers notified with real delays :

```
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var log = source.Take(5).Timestamp().ToList().Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Time now is " + DateTime.Now);
var scheduler = new HistoricalScheduler();
var replay = Observable.Generate(
 log.GetEnumerator(),
 events => events.MoveNext(),
 events => events,
 events => events.Current.Value,
 events => events.Current.Timestamp,
 scheduler);

replay.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Event: {0} happened at {1}", i, scheduler.Now));
scheduler.Start();
```